# Export to csv ExtJS

Tags: csv, extjs, export

I'm trying to export data to csv format. I use ExtJS 3.2.1
The code is as follows:

this.getEl (). child ('a', true). href = 'data: text / csv; filename = datos.csv; charset = UTF-8 2CPrice% Company% 2CChange% 2C% 25% 20Change% 2CLast% 20Updated% 0d% 0a3m% 20Co, 71.72,0.02,0.03, Wed% 20Sep% 2001% 202010% 2000% 3A00% 3A00% 20GMT% 2B0200% 20 (CET)% 0d% 0aAlcoa% 20Inc, 29.01,0.42,1.47, Wed % 20Sep% 2001% 202010% 2000% 3A00% 3A00% 20GMT% 2B0200% 20 (CET) '

I'm using firefox and always generates a file with the extension .part
Why is putting the browser extension .part? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

.part is the name given to partially downloaded files no?

what server side tech are you using? i'd seriously consider doing the export server side - this is not a browser concern - you will probably need to re-gen the dataset but you'll have a lot more control and less fudd.

If you're using .net I have some code that might help - it uses the OOXML library from MS and uses the extjs grid config to generate and XLS - with exactly the same attributes (same grouping, columns, sorting etc).